# How to rotate a Zone in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Does anyone know how to rotate a Zone in Phaser 3 ?

I'm trying to setup 3 Zones (registered in a this.zones object) in order to detect collisions but I can't achieve that, nothing I tried works, neither with this.zones.gauche.angle = 45 nor with this.zones.gauche.setAngle(45).
In the console, my zones seem to be rotated, but they aren't in the game window (I can see them because they are added to a physics arcade static group with debug on).
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks !

A bit of code :

```
create () {
  this.zones.fond     = this.add.zone(0, 0).setSize(game.CONFIG.width, 170);
  this.zones.gauche   = this.add.zone(0, 0).setSize(170, game.CONFIG.width).setAngle(45);
  this.zones.droite   = this.add.zone(737, 208, 170, game.CONFIG.width).setAngle(-45);

  this.objets.zones   = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
  this.objets.zones.add(this.zones.fond);
  this.objets.zones.add(this.zones.gauche);
  this.objets.zones.add(this.zones.droite);
}// create () {
```

[EDIT] The documentation tells it's possible : https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Zone.html#angle__anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate a Zone, but in your code, you are creating Arcade Physics Bodies, not Zones, and the limitation of any Arcade Physics object is that it cannot rotate. It uses AABB only. You'll need to use Matter.js if you'd like to rotate your physics body.

Comment: Well, I solved that using a good old math solution : with y = ax + b, I manage to know where is located my Sprite. No more arcade bodies nor zones.
Thank you again and have a nice day !